# How to pass value from javascript to aspx?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, browser

i had a javascript to detect user broswer width and want to pass the width to aspx.vb.

```
function chk_width() {
 var winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById("hiddenfieldsize").value = winW;
// alert(winW);
} 

<body onLoad="chk_width()">
```

i had tried to use the following code, but i cannot get the value.

```
Dim WinWdth As String = Request.Form("hiddenfieldsize").ToString
```

Joe

Comment: Hmm, could you show the markup for `hiddenfieldsize`? Also, are you sure the form is being posted *after* this function is called when you are checking for it in server code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get value at server by set server control's value in javascript. I have illustrate the code below. hope it will be helpful to you.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenfieldsize" />

function chk_width() {
 var winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
document.getElementById("<%=hiddenfieldsize.ClientID %>").value= winW;     
} 

$(document).ready(function() {
  chk_width();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run script after page load. You may put script to footer. 
when your code run. Hiddenfield may be unloaded.

You may run this script on your page. IF Your page has got Jquery Reference.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  chk_width();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass it back server side you will need to post the data.  You would have to use AJAX for this.